# sample code for macros - the same (kind of) error

Tags: macros, clojure

I have read the macros tutorial from the 
http://www.learningclojure.com/2010/09/clojure-macro-tutorial-part-i-getting.html site and I don't understand how to debug some errors. 
Could somebody describe what is wrong/not correct?

- the simple version

> ```
> (defmacro dbgm_v1 [s] 
>    (list 'let ['a s] (list 'println (list 'quote s) "=" 'a) 'a)
> )
> ```

```
;;;;
```

> ```
> (defn factorial_v1 [n] 
>    (if (< n 2) n
>         (dbgm_v1 (* n factorial_v1(dec n)) )
>     ) 
> )
> ```

```
;;

; let's test it
```

> ```
> (factorial_v1 5) 
> ClassCastException clojure.dg.alfa01$factorial_v1 cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.Numbers.multiply (Numbers.java:146)
> ```

- the complex version

> ```
> (defmacro dbgm_v9 [x] 
>   `(let  [x# ~x] (println '~x "=" x#) x#)
> )
> ```

```
;
```

> ```
> (defn factorial_v9 [n]
>   (if (< n 2) n
>     (dbgm_v9 (* n factorial_v9 (dec n)))
> ))
> ```

```
;
```

> ```
> user=> (factorial_v9 5)
> ClassCastException clojure.dg.alfa01$factorial_v9 cannot be cast to java.lang.Nu
> mber  clojure.lang.Numbers.multiply (Numbers.java:146)
> user=>
> ```

It fails with the same error.

What is wrong with the above code? 
Thank you in advance for any hint/url/notes !

DG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an opening parenthesis.

```
(defmacro dbgm_v9 [x] 
  `(let  [x# ~x] (println '~x "=" x#) x#))

(defn factorial_v9 [n]
  (if (< n 2) n
    (dbgm_v9 (* n (factorial_v9 (dec n))))))
                 ;^ Missing (
(factorial_v9 5) ;=> 120
```

You can verify how your macro expands with [`macroexpand`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/macroexpand).

```
(macroexpand '(dbgm_v9 (* n factorial_v9 (dec n))))
;=>
(let* [x__31341__auto__ (* n factorial_v9 (dec n))]
  (clojure.core/println (quote (* n factorial_v9 (dec n))) "=" x__31341__auto__)
  x__31341__auto__)
```

The exception was caused when `*` tried to operate on `n`, `factorial_v9`, and `(dec n)`. Since `*` operates on numbers, it tried to cast `factorial_v9` to a number and failed.